# Mongo DB how to separate concerns

Tags: mongodb

I've got these scripts that run every 10 seconds and write thousands of entries to a database.

I then have a web app that consumes the same database.

Is there a problem with that, and if so, how can I separate the concerns of constant writes with the reading.  Should I have 2 separate DBs and once a day do mass writes to the one? Not sure.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem. That's what databases are for.

Comment: You may run into severe problems. MongoDB is [known](https://aphyr.com/posts/322-call-me-maybe-mongodb-stale-reads) to have some serious flaws in some scenarios especially if you write a lot of data in a short time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo can handle massive simultaneous reads and writes (as long as your queries and indexes are setup properly), so in general, this is not a problem.

However, if you need these writes to happen every 10 seconds, then read the data only after it is all written, you may need to add in extra code to time everything properly.  This isn't a problem with Mongo itself, it would be a concern for your application.

Depending on how you "consume" the data, you may want to look into capped collections.

Also look into using the WiredTiger storage engine if you have a lot of writes.  However, whether you use MMAP or WiredTiger, you shouldn't run into any problems with reads and writes, unless you have a massive collection, in which case, you may want to separate your data into more collections to speed up find queries.